# Comparing different ListPlot3D outputs between different data sets

Tags: plotting, visualization

I have data for the bed of a river that consists of several cross profiles over several years. I have used the elevation measurements with Northing and Easting coordinates to create ListPlot3D visuals of the riverbed, with the mesh giving an estimate and visual aid to how the riverbed looks (only an estimate of course). Below is an example of the data for one of the years, the different sections are above and below a dam, so I made sure they are not connected. The purple dots are the elevation measurements used.
[image]

Below is the code I used to create the ListPlot3D and add the measured points.

```
All2021=Show[ListPlot3D[{AllPntsD2021, AllPntsU2021},BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.2}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},PlotStyle -> Opacity@0.75,AxesLabel -> {"Northing", "Easting", "Elevation"}],Graphics3D[{Purple, PointSize[0.008],Point /@ {AllPntsD2021, AllPntsU2021}}]]
```

I would like to somehow show the differences in the riverbed from one year to the other, but just comparing the images themselves is very difficult, as even a meter of difference is hard to spot. The best method I have thought of is using colors to represent areas that have a lower or higher elevation than in previous years. I am still relatively new to coding and Mathematica so haven't been able to come up with either a solution to make comparing easier or a method to show differences with color.

Any help on methods I could use to compare the data from different years with some rudimentary code to get me in the right direction would be appreciated.

*I have been using the technique below in @JimB's answer for my data for a single section of the river and it has been working well. However, when I use the method for another area of the river and change nothing but the input data, it gives the errors in the below photo (with the "insufficient quality" varying depending on the years being compared). I thought this error would not occur anymore because of the added step that worked for the other section of the river.
[image]

*Some data for another section of the river this method is not working for

```
{{4964.53, 5016.07, 102.514}, {4964.72, 5015.26, 100.969}, {4964.83, 
  5014.82, 101.046}, {4964.93, 5014.42, 100.868}, {4965.05, 5013.89, 
  100.777}, {4965.17, 5013.4, 100.811}, {4965.32, 5012.8, 
  100.78}, {4965.43, 5012.34, 100.776}, {4965.56, 5011.77, 
  100.85}, {4965.68, 5011.29, 100.66}, {4965.82, 5010.71, 
  100.615}, {4965.93, 5010.26, 100.616}, {4966.05, 5009.76, 
  100.567}, {4966.16, 5009.29, 100.508}, {4966.3, 5008.71, 
  100.494}, {4966.41, 5008.25, 100.475}, {4966.55, 5007.69, 
  100.427}, {4966.67, 5007.19, 100.391}, {4966.79, 5006.69, 
  100.382}, {4966.91, 5006.19, 100.351}, {4967.04, 5005.63, 
  100.31}, {4967.15, 5005.16, 100.294}, {4967.29, 5004.61, 
  100.311}, {4967.4, 5004.14, 100.35}, {4967.53, 5003.62, 
  100.373}, {4967.64, 5003.13, 100.379}, {4967.77, 5002.59, 
  100.379}, {4967.88, 5002.13, 100.401}, {4968.03, 5001.54, 
  100.414}, {4968.14, 5001.08, 100.362}, {4968.27, 5000.55, 
  100.39}, {4968.37, 5000.13, 100.27}, {4968.51, 4999.52, 
  100.272}, {4968.63, 4999.04, 100.27}, {4968.75, 4998.53, 
  100.225}, {4968.86, 4998.06, 100.264}, {4969., 4997.48, 
  100.203}, {4969.11, 4997.06, 100.229}, {4969.25, 4996.44, 
  100.228}, {4969.35, 4996.05, 100.249}, {4969.49, 4995.45, 
  100.252}, {4969.59, 4995.06, 100.284}, {4969.73, 4994.45, 
  100.203}, {4969.84, 4993.99, 100.123}, {4969.98, 4993.44, 
  100.082}, {4970.09, 4992.97, 100.059}, {4970.23, 4992.4, 
  100.265}, {4970.32, 4992.01, 100.386}, {4970.46, 4991.43, 
  100.367}, {4970.56, 4991.01, 100.447}, {4970.7, 4990.43, 
  100.704}, {4970.81, 4989.96, 100.846}, {4970.94, 4989.45, 
  100.747}, {4971.06, 4988.95, 101.024}, {4971.18, 4988.43, 
  101.175}, {4971.29, 4988., 101.321}, {4971.43, 4987.42, 
  101.312}, {4971.53, 4986.97, 101.293}, {4971.67, 4986.41, 
  101.43}, {4971.78, 4985.93, 101.571}, {4971.9, 4985.43, 
  102.234}, {4972.02, 4984.97, 102.372}, {4972.14, 4984.43, 
  102.603}, {4972.23, 4984.07, 102.738}, {4948.22, 5009.29, 
  100.705}, {4948.3, 5008.86, 100.705}, {4948.44, 5008.15, 
  100.575}, {4948.54, 5007.62, 100.406}, {4948.62, 5007.23, 
  100.431}, {4948.73, 5006.69, 100.428}, {4948.84, 5006.13, 
  100.543}, {4948.94, 5005.64, 100.631}, {4949.04, 5005.11, 
  100.641}, {4949.15, 5004.55, 100.675}, {4949.26, 5004.03, 
  100.614}, {4949.34, 5003.59, 100.619}, {4949.45, 5003.05, 
  100.681}, {4949.51, 5002.72, 100.605}, {4949.65, 5002.01, 
  100.597}, {4949.79, 5001.34, 100.546}, {4949.87, 5000.94, 
  100.557}, {4949.96, 5000.45, 100.585}, {4950.06, 4999.94, 
  100.583}, {4950.18, 4999.38, 100.577}, {4950.27, 4998.92, 
  100.548}, {4950.36, 4998.45, 100.547}, {4950.48, 4997.84, 
  100.528}, {4950.57, 4997.38, 100.56}, {4950.68, 4996.84, 
  100.496}, {4950.77, 4996.38, 100.504}, {4950.89, 4995.77, 
  100.512}, {4950.99, 4995.27, 100.455}, {4951.09, 4994.73, 
  100.488}, {4951.18, 4994.32, 100.449}, {4951.28, 4993.8, 
  100.424}, {4951.39, 4993.25, 100.34}, {4951.48, 4992.79, 
  100.347}, {4951.59, 4992.25, 100.338}, {4951.71, 4991.63, 
  100.288}, {4951.79, 4991.22, 100.281}, {4951.91, 4990.6, 
  100.358}, {4951.99, 4990.2, 100.272}, {4952.11, 4989.61, 
  100.284}, {4952.19, 4989.19, 100.26}, {4952.31, 4988.57, 
  100.23}, {4952.4, 4988.16, 100.218}, {4952.52, 4987.54, 
  100.075}, {4952.6, 4987.1, 99.955}, {4952.72, 4986.5, 
  99.798}, {4952.8, 4986.11, 99.775}, {4952.92, 4985.5, 
  99.887}, {4953., 4985.08, 100.152}, {4953.12, 4984.5, 
  100.254}, {4953.21, 4984.03, 100.565}, {4953.33, 4983.43, 
  100.766}, {4953.41, 4983.01, 100.896}, {4953.54, 4982.39, 
  101.232}, {4953.63, 4981.94, 101.166}, {4953.73, 4981.4, 
  101.481}, {4953.84, 4980.88, 102.135}, {4953.93, 4980.38, 
  102.364}, {4954.03, 4979.9, 102.418}, {4932.53, 5004.97, 
  100.536}, {4932.62, 5004.62, 100.539}, {4932.77, 5004.06, 
  100.545}, {4932.92, 5003.48, 100.539}, {4933.04, 5002.99, 
  100.609}, {4933.17, 5002.5, 100.618}, {4933.33, 5001.91, 
  100.582}, {4933.46, 5001.41, 100.557}, {4933.62, 5000.78, 
  100.592}, {4933.73, 5000.37, 100.584}, {4933.85, 4999.92, 
  100.637}, {4933.96, 4999.46, 100.655}, {4934.1, 4998.93, 
  100.643}, {4934.25, 4998.39, 100.601}, {4934.37, 4997.9, 
  100.595}, {4934.49, 4997.45, 100.616}, {4934.62, 4996.94, 
  100.658}, {4934.78, 4996.36, 100.601}, {4934.89, 4995.91, 
  100.618}, {4935.04, 4995.34, 100.655}, {4935.17, 4994.84, 
  100.607}, {4935.33, 4994.24, 100.589}, {4935.5, 4993.56, 
  100.52}, {4935.6, 4993.2, 100.523}, {4935.66, 4992.95, 
  100.496}, {4935.8, 4992.45, 100.471}, {4935.94, 4991.88, 
  100.465}, {4936.1, 4991.29, 100.374}, {4936.16, 4991.04, 
  100.361}, {4936.33, 4990.39, 100.358}, {4936.42, 4990.05, 
  100.352}, {4936.6, 4989.36, 100.37}, {4936.72, 4988.91, 
  100.34}, {4936.87, 4988.33, 100.366}, {4936.98, 4987.91, 
  100.35}, {4937.13, 4987.33, 100.328}, {4937.3, 4986.68, 
  100.325}, {4937.43, 4986.19, 100.345}, {4937.55, 4985.7, 
  100.35}, {4937.7, 4985.14, 100.338}, {4937.84, 4984.62, 
  100.341}, {4937.94, 4984.23, 100.356}, {4938.1, 4983.61, 
  100.308}, {4938.31, 4982.8, 100.062}, {4938.46, 4982.23, 
  99.979}, {4938.54, 4981.92, 99.892}, {4938.86, 4980.7, 
  100.128}, {4939.03, 4980.05, 100.197}, {4939.15, 4979.58, 
  100.345}, {4939.26, 4979.17, 100.624}, {4939.42, 4978.56, 
  100.76}, {4939.54, 4978.07, 100.968}, {4939.88, 4976.8, 
  102.474}, {4939.97, 4976.42, 102.578}, {4910.13, 5002.58, 
  101.287}, {4910.22, 5001.96, 100.827}, {4910.26, 5001.7, 
  100.409}, {4910.37, 5000.96, 100.519}, {4910.43, 5000.5, 
  100.525}, {4910.51, 4999.94, 100.555}, {4910.58, 4999.45, 
  100.558}, {4910.66, 4998.87, 100.558}, {4910.72, 4998.47, 
  100.524}, {4910.81, 4997.86, 100.487}, {4910.87, 4997.43, 
  100.496}, {4910.95, 4996.85, 100.488}, {4911.02, 4996.4, 
  100.465}, {4911.11, 4995.76, 100.483}, {4911.16, 4995.37, 
  100.493}, {4911.32, 4994.29, 100.451}, {4911.4, 4993.73, 
  100.455}, {4911.46, 4993.29, 100.41}, {4911.54, 4992.71, 
  100.391}, {4911.61, 4992.23, 100.439}, {4911.7, 4991.64, 
  100.435}, {4911.76, 4991.16, 100.423}, {4911.85, 4990.56, 
  100.448}, {4911.9, 4990.2, 100.456}, {4912., 4989.52, 
  100.362}, {4912.06, 4989.1, 100.339}, {4912.13, 4988.59, 
  100.31}, {4912.2, 4988.11, 100.295}, {4912.28, 4987.52, 
  100.29}, {4912.35, 4987.08, 100.176}, {4912.4, 4986.68, 
  100.168}, {4912.48, 4986.13, 100.146}, {4912.59, 4985.36, 
  100.181}, {4912.64, 4985.01, 100.206}, {4912.74, 4984.33, 
  100.265}, {4912.79, 4983.97, 100.258}, {4913.02, 4982.37, 
  100.31}, {4913.11, 4981.74, 100.366}, {4913.17, 4981.3, 
  100.395}, {4913.25, 4980.76, 100.428}, {4913.33, 4980.18, 
  100.435}, {4913.39, 4979.75, 100.38}, {4913.44, 4979.39, 
  100.547}, {4913.54, 4978.72, 100.485}, {4913.6, 4978.27, 
  100.481}, {4913.67, 4977.79, 100.753}, {4913.75, 4977.25, 
  100.857}, {4913.81, 4976.86, 101.189}, {4889.21, 4996.29, 
  99.877}, {4889.3, 4995.84, 99.887}, {4889.42, 4995.27, 
  99.931}, {4889.51, 4994.84, 99.968}, {4889.64, 4994.18, 
  99.965}, {4889.71, 4993.83, 99.967}, {4889.84, 4993.22, 
  99.976}, {4890.51, 4989.96, 100.085}, {4890.82, 4988.44, 
  100.087}, {4890.91, 4988., 100.113}, {4891.01, 4987.54, 
  100.046}, {4891.09, 4987.13, 100.06}, {4891.18, 4986.69, 
  100.009}, {4891.31, 4986.09, 99.969}, {4891.4, 4985.66, 
  99.883}, {4891.52, 4985.03, 99.812}, {4891.63, 4984.54, 
  99.771}, {4892.12, 4982.15, 99.647}, {4892.24, 4981.58, 
  99.53}, {4892.35, 4981.01, 99.489}, {4892.47, 4980.47, 
  99.484}, {4892.6, 4979.83, 99.571}, {4892.67, 4979.45, 
  99.984}, {4892.81, 4978.81, 99.837}, {4892.91, 4978.31, 
  100.148}, {4893.07, 4977.52, 100.192}, {4893.22, 4976.8, 
  100.405}, {4893.31, 4976.39, 100.519}, {4893.4, 4975.93, 
  100.669}, {4893.5, 4975.43, 100.837}, {4893.82, 4973.87, 
  101.944}, {4894.2, 4972.04, 102.556}}
```

```
{{4964.66, 5015.52, 101.481}, {4964.77, 5015.06, 101.097}, {4964.89, 
  5014.56, 100.933}, {4965., 5014.13, 100.751}, {4965.12, 5013.62, 
  100.762}, {4965.22, 5013.19, 100.774}, {4965.34, 5012.7, 
  100.768}, {4965.46, 5012.19, 100.805}, {4965.58, 5011.7, 
  100.816}, {4965.69, 5011.25, 100.804}, {4965.81, 5010.75, 
  100.793}, {4965.93, 5010.24, 100.783}, {4966.05, 5009.77, 
  100.775}, {4966.16, 5009.28, 100.785}, {4966.28, 5008.78, 
  100.791}, {4966.4, 5008.28, 100.753}, {4966.51, 5007.83, 
  100.755}, {4966.61, 5007.41, 100.735}, {4966.75, 5006.86, 
  100.71}, {4966.86, 5006.38, 100.662}, {4966.96, 5005.95, 
  100.62}, {4967.09, 5005.42, 100.607}, {4967.22, 5004.91, 
  100.583}, {4967.32, 5004.46, 100.583}, {4967.44, 5003.96, 
  100.572}, {4967.57, 5003.44, 100.579}, {4967.67, 5003.01, 
  100.601}, {4967.8, 5002.48, 100.594}, {4967.92, 5001.99, 
  100.59}, {4968.04, 5001.48, 100.599}, {4968.16, 5001., 
  100.538}, {4968.27, 5000.53, 100.521}, {4968.4, 5000., 
  100.529}, {4968.51, 4999.53, 100.523}, {4968.63, 4999.03, 
  100.511}, {4968.74, 4998.57, 100.488}, {4968.88, 4997.98, 
  100.466}, {4968.97, 4997.62, 100.447}, {4969.11, 4997.04, 
  100.425}, {4969.23, 4996.55, 100.413}, {4969.31, 4996.2, 
  100.389}, {4969.47, 4995.54, 100.382}, {4969.58, 4995.1, 
  100.372}, {4969.68, 4994.65, 100.344}, {4969.8, 4994.19, 
  100.312}, {4969.93, 4993.64, 100.25}, {4970.04, 4993.16, 
  100.283}, {4970.16, 4992.66, 100.283}, {4970.27, 4992.2, 
  100.323}, {4970.4, 4991.69, 100.397}, {4970.53, 4991.16, 
  100.621}, {4970.63, 4990.71, 100.595}, {4970.74, 4990.27, 
  100.756}, {4970.86, 4989.76, 100.925}, {4970.98, 4989.27, 
  101.023}, {4971.09, 4988.8, 101.096}, {4971.24, 4988.18, 
  101.121}, {4971.36, 4987.69, 101.298}, {4971.48, 4987.19, 
  101.301}, {4971.59, 4986.73, 101.443}, {4971.7, 4986.26, 
  101.53}, {4971.85, 4985.65, 101.747}, {4971.95, 4985.24, 
  101.97}, {4972.07, 4984.74, 102.21}, {4972.19, 4984.26, 
  102.485}, {4972.3, 4983.8, 102.7}, {4948.33, 5008.71, 
  100.705}, {4948.41, 5008.29, 100.57}, {4948.5, 5007.86, 
  100.513}, {4948.59, 5007.41, 100.508}, {4948.91, 5005.77, 
  100.525}, {4948.99, 5005.39, 100.511}, {4949.09, 5004.85, 
  100.485}, {4949.24, 5004.1, 100.435}, {4949.45, 5003.06, 
  100.504}, {4949.52, 5002.7, 100.509}, {4949.61, 5002.26, 
  100.506}, {4949.66, 5001.99, 100.469}, {4949.78, 5001.38, 
  100.478}, {4949.88, 5000.89, 100.515}, {4949.97, 5000.44, 
  100.511}, {4950.07, 4999.93, 100.5}, {4950.13, 4999.59, 
  100.488}, {4950.24, 4999.07, 100.479}, {4950.33, 4998.58, 
  100.474}, {4950.43, 4998.1, 100.459}, {4950.55, 4997.47, 
  100.451}, {4950.61, 4997.18, 100.473}, {4950.74, 4996.53, 
  100.475}, {4950.83, 4996.04, 100.476}, {4950.93, 4995.57, 
  100.465}, {4951.01, 4995.15, 100.461}, {4951.12, 4994.6, 
  100.428}, {4951.21, 4994.16, 100.421}, {4951.33, 4993.55, 
  100.378}, {4951.41, 4993.15, 100.368}, {4951.49, 4992.73, 
  100.322}, {4951.6, 4992.19, 100.325}, {4951.69, 4991.72, 
  100.262}, {4951.77, 4991.31, 100.263}, {4951.88, 4990.78, 
  100.219}, {4951.98, 4990.26, 100.211}, {4952.08, 4989.75, 
  100.165}, {4952.15, 4989.38, 100.14}, {4952.25, 4988.91, 
  100.087}, {4952.34, 4988.46, 99.979}, {4952.45, 4987.91, 
  99.94}, {4952.54, 4987.42, 99.903}, {4952.64, 4986.92, 
  99.93}, {4952.73, 4986.48, 99.869}, {4952.8, 4986.1, 
  99.888}, {4952.92, 4985.51, 99.927}, {4953., 4985.1, 
  99.964}, {4953.09, 4984.63, 100.109}, {4953.2, 4984.07, 
  100.402}, {4933.56, 5001.03, 100.382}, {4933.65, 5000.67, 
  100.392}, {4933.78, 5000.19, 100.42}, {4933.91, 4999.68, 
  100.479}, {4934.02, 4999.25, 100.517}, {4934.14, 4998.78, 
  100.519}, {4934.27, 4998.31, 100.524}, {4934.39, 4997.82, 
  100.548}, {4934.53, 4997.31, 100.534}, {4934.64, 4996.89, 
  100.525}, {4934.75, 4996.44, 100.517}, {4934.89, 4995.9, 
  100.489}, {4935.01, 4995.44, 100.48}, {4935.13, 4994.99, 
  100.462}, {4935.28, 4994.42, 100.464}, {4935.4, 4993.98, 
  100.456}, {4935.53, 4993.46, 100.444}, {4935.64, 4993.03, 
  100.466}, {4935.79, 4992.47, 100.462}, {4935.91, 4992.02, 
  100.43}, {4936.02, 4991.56, 100.418}, {4936.18, 4990.99, 
  100.441}, {4936.29, 4990.53, 100.414}, {4936.43, 4990.02, 
  100.402}, {4936.63, 4989.23, 100.361}, {4936.69, 4989.03, 
  100.351}, {4936.8, 4988.6, 100.341}, {4936.93, 4988.11, 
  100.308}, {4937.06, 4987.58, 100.287}, {4937.17, 4987.18, 
  100.283}, {4937.3, 4986.67, 100.244}, {4937.43, 4986.17, 
  100.199}, {4937.56, 4985.68, 100.182}, {4937.68, 4985.23, 
  100.139}, {4937.81, 4984.73, 100.045}, {4937.93, 4984.25, 
  99.957}, {4938.06, 4983.75, 99.915}, {4938.18, 4983.28, 
  99.883}, {4938.31, 4982.81, 99.947}, {4938.44, 4982.29, 
  99.839}, {4938.57, 4981.81, 99.849}, {4938.71, 4981.25, 
  99.944}, {4938.83, 4980.8, 99.95}, {4938.95, 4980.33, 
  100.109}, {4939.07, 4979.88, 100.203}, {4939.2, 4979.38, 
  100.304}, {4939.32, 4978.91, 100.461}, {4939.41, 4978.59, 
  100.896}, {4939.56, 4978., 100.965}, {4939.78, 4977.17, 
  101.195}, {4939.95, 4976.5, 101.534}, {4939.92, 4976.61, 
  101.705}, {4910.25, 5001.75, 101.718}, {4910.3, 5001.45, 
  101.64}, {4910.33, 5001.24, 101.546}, {4910.4, 5000.74, 
  100.399}, {4910.47, 5000.24, 100.257}, {4910.53, 4999.78, 
  100.274}, {4910.6, 4999.31, 100.228}, {4910.66, 4998.87, 
  100.218}, {4910.74, 4998.36, 100.234}, {4910.81, 4997.88, 
  100.292}, {4910.88, 4997.37, 100.313}, {4910.95, 4996.85, 
  100.399}, {4911.02, 4996.37, 100.41}, {4911.09, 4995.89, 
  100.433}, {4911.16, 4995.43, 100.456}, {4911.23, 4994.9, 
  100.451}, {4911.3, 4994.43, 100.456}, {4911.37, 4993.89, 
  100.426}, {4911.43, 4993.5, 100.419}, {4911.48, 4993.15, 
  100.44}, {4911.56, 4992.57, 100.479}, {4911.61, 4992.21, 
  100.491}, {4911.77, 4991.14, 100.411}, {4911.85, 4990.57, 
  100.427}, {4911.92, 4990.1, 100.417}, {4911.97, 4989.69, 
  100.431}, {4912.05, 4989.15, 100.408}, {4912.12, 4988.7, 
  100.346}, {4912.18, 4988.25, 100.337}, {4912.26, 4987.72, 
  100.32}, {4912.32, 4987.3, 100.295}, {4912.4, 4986.7, 
  100.281}, {4912.47, 4986.18, 100.276}, {4912.54, 4985.73, 
  100.263}, {4912.59, 4985.34, 100.229}, {4912.66, 4984.87, 
  100.194}, {4912.74, 4984.33, 100.145}, {4912.82, 4983.79, 
  100.128}, {4912.87, 4983.4, 100.09}, {4912.96, 4982.78, 
  100.049}, {4913.01, 4982.43, 100.027}, {4913.16, 4981.36, 
  100.02}, {4913.24, 4980.85, 100.085}, {4913.31, 4980.33, 
  100.188}, {4913.39, 4979.79, 99.925}, {4913.45, 4979.34, 
  99.85}, {4913.52, 4978.85, 99.794}, {4913.59, 4978.4, 
  99.802}, {4913.64, 4978.01, 99.905}, {4913.73, 4977.38, 
  100.235}, {4913.8, 4976.89, 100.407}, {4913.88, 4976.31, 
  100.642}, {4913.95, 4975.83, 100.963}, {4914.01, 4975.44, 
  101.075}, {4914.08, 4974.95, 101.15}, {4914.15, 4974.45, 
  101.271}, {4914.23, 4973.86, 101.477}, {4914.27, 4973.58, 
  101.64}, {4889.39, 4995.38, 100.081}, {4889.48, 4994.98, 
  99.98}, {4889.58, 4994.49, 99.943}, {4889.67, 4994.05, 
  99.947}, {4889.76, 4993.59, 99.956}, {4889.84, 4993.2, 
  99.915}, {4889.96, 4992.62, 99.997}, {4890.06, 4992.13, 
  100.058}, {4890.16, 4991.65, 100.02}, {4890.26, 4991.17, 
  100.071}, {4890.35, 4990.74, 100.086}, {4890.45, 4990.26, 
  100.063}, {4890.57, 4989.69, 100.055}, {4890.65, 4989.29, 
  100.08}, {4890.74, 4988.86, 100.081}, {4890.86, 4988.27, 
  100.119}, {4890.94, 4987.86, 100.183}, {4891.03, 4987.44, 
  100.173}, {4891.14, 4986.9, 100.176}, {4891.24, 4986.44, 
  100.182}, {4891.34, 4985.95, 100.185}, {4891.43, 4985.5, 
  100.204}, {4891.53, 4985., 100.194}, {4891.63, 4984.51, 
  100.234}, {4891.73, 4984.03, 100.184}, {4892.05, 4982.5, 
  100.181}, {4892.13, 4982.08, 100.164}, {4892.25, 4981.52, 
  100.17}, {4892.35, 4981.04, 100.157}, {4892.41, 4980.73, 
  100.132}, {4892.53, 4980.16, 100.12}, {4892.64, 4979.62, 
  100.101}, {4892.81, 4978.79, 100.005}, {4892.94, 4978.15, 
  99.962}, {4893.06, 4977.56, 99.9}, {4893.17, 4977.06, 
  100.005}, {4893.22, 4976.79, 100.181}, {4893.37, 4976.08, 
  100.368}, {4893.43, 4975.77, 100.44}, {4893.58, 4975.08, 
  100.731}, {4893.67, 4974.62, 100.97}, {4893.78, 4974.07, 
  101.233}, {4893.86, 4973.7, 101.729}, {4893.94, 4973.32, 101.63}}
```

Comment: Because you're looking for change over time, subtract out the elevations from "Year 1" from each year.  If you have $n$ years, either show separately the $n-1$ difference plots or produce an animation if the $n-1$ difference plots.

Comment: Or plot one surface over the other, using `Style -> Opacity[0.5]` for the "top" surface.

Comment: @JimB  the exact measurements between years are not taken at the exact same location each year, with the measurements falling along a straight line but at varying places along these lines. I have splines created for each of the cross-sections, would there be a way for me to use the splines to create the mesh rather than the individual points? If so I can use the difference in the splines I created to show change at each cross-section to make a mesh map.

Comment: But you have a mesh for each year.  The measurements (even at different location each year) are used to create an estimate of the elevations at every point of interest.  I don't see the absolute need for the same points every year.

Comment: @JimB So am I correct in understanding what you are saying is I can find the differences between the meshes? If so what command would I use for that? I've tried finding a way to do that but have been unsuccessful so far. I'm quite new to this still and don't have the strongest background in mathematics

Comment: You can probably use `Interpolation`.

Comment: Thanks for adding the data.  But it appears that a large percentage of the `{Easting, Northing}` values have multiple elevations.  Should those be averaged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to know where one year is higher or lower than another, then @DavidGStork 's suggestion works fine:

```
Show[ListPlot3D[{AllPntsU2019, AllPntsU2018}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.2},
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, PlotStyle -> Opacity@0.75,
  AxesLabel -> {"Northing", "Easting", "Elevation"},
  SphericalRegion -> True, RotationAction -> "Clip"],
 Graphics3D[{Purple, PointSize[0.008], 
   Point /@ {AllPntsU2019, AllPntsU2018}}]]
```

[image: Overlay of 2019 and 2018 elevation data]

The "blue" areas are where 2019 elevations are higher than 2018 and the "orange" areas are where the 2019 elevations are lower than 2018.

If you want to estimate the size of the differences, then as you pointed out such a display doesn't allow one to do so given that the differences are relatively small compared to the range of all elevations.  In that case maybe constructing a contour plot of the differences in elevation from one year to the next  might be useful.

```
(* Use mean elevation at points with the same Easting and Northing *)
d2018 = If[Length[#] > 1, {#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], Mean[#[[All, 3]]]}, #[[1]]] & /@ 
   GatherBy[AllPntsU2018, {#[[1]], #[[2]]} &];
d2019 = If[Length[#] > 1, {#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], Mean[#[[All, 3]]]}, #[[1]]] & /@ 
   GatherBy[AllPntsU2019, {#[[1]], #[[2]]} &];

(* In hopes of avoiding lack-of-precision issues, subtract off the 
minimum Easting and Northing from both datasets for better results 
from Interpolation *)
{minEasting, maxEasting} = MinMax[Join[AllPntsU2018[[All, 1]], AllPntsU2019[[All, 1]]]];
{minNorthing, maxNorthing} = MinMax[Join[AllPntsU2018[[All, 2]], AllPntsU2019[[All, 2]]]];
d2018 = # - {minEasting, minNorthing, 0} & /@ AllPntsU2018;
d2019 = # - {minEasting, minNorthing, 0} & /@ AllPntsU2019;

(* Construct interpolation functions *)
f2019 = Interpolation[d2019]; // Quiet
f2018 = Interpolation[d2018]; // Quiet

(* Create a grid of differences between the two years *)
diff = Flatten[Table[{easting, northing, 
  f2019[easting - minEasting, northing - minNorthing] - 
  f2018[easting - minEasting, northing - minNorthing]},
  {easting, minEasting, maxEasting, (maxEasting - minEasting)/100},
  {northing, minNorthing, maxNorthing, (maxNorthing - minNorthing)/100}], 1] // Quiet;

(* Restrict points that are within the area of the sampled locations *)
p = RegionIntersection[ConvexHullRegion[AllPntsU2018[[All, {1, 2}]]], 
  ConvexHullRegion[AllPntsU2019[[All, {1, 2}]]]];
diff2 = Select[diff, Element[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, p] &];
ListContourPlot[diff2, MaxPlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Contour plot of elevation differences]

If more detailed differences are needed, then looking at each transect separately would be the way to go.

Comment: When I try to interpolate some of my data, I get the error below. It doesn't do it for the data for every year and there are no significant differences between the data from different years (only a max of 50cm between years). "The element mesh has insufficient quality of -0.0000382122. A \quality estimate below 0. may be caused by a wrong ordering of \element incidents or self-intersecting elements." Any idea how to fix this? I have looked up the error and how to fix on mathematical but found the solution very confusing

Comment: Can you share the data?  Or maybe some random translation of the data that doesn't change the shape?

Comment: I have added two years of data above. For the year 2021, interpolating the data did not come up with the error, but this data (in the same format imported in the same way) did result in the error.

Comment: Thanks!  Your original figure seems to show that *Mathematica* did some interpolation correctly otherwise you wouldn't have been able produce that figure.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I think the contour plot is definitely the best solution and coupled with the simple 3D meshes and individual cross profiles I have for each of the sections, the data will be much easier to interpret and visualize. I think also that @DavidGStork's suggestion will be useful also now I see the possibilities of showing sections that overlap without nececesarily needing to know exact values in differences. The help has been much appreciated! I'm just a simple geologist trying to slowly learn some code for my research

Comment: I am getting errors when I try to use this method on my data. It took me a second to figure out the situation with the Northings and Eastings with different elevations. I realized when I copied them from Mathematica the decimals didn't copy over. I updated the data above to be accurate with the decimals. Because of this, I tried the method with and without the first step that averages the elevations but got the following error ("The element mesh has insufficient quality of \ -0.00004466306823739188`"). I've added a photo of the errors that show up when the first step is included also

Comment: It turns out (which I didn't know until now) that `Interpolation` on an unstructured grid can only use machine precision.  When one uses UTM's many times the numbers have many digits and like in this case the first 3 or 4 digits are common among all values.  That results in a loss of numerical precision.  So in an attempt to get around that subtract off a common minimum from the Easting and subtract off a common minimum from the Northing from both datasets.  I'll update the answer to accommodate that issue.

Comment: It seems to be working as intended now, I appreciate the update! would you have any recommendations for adjusting the ColorFuntion so that the scale is the same when doing this method for data from all the other years? E.g. values equal to 0 are white values at -2.5 are dark red, values at 2.5 are green and the colors in between are a regular gradient from this dark red to green. Potentially with the contours at regular intervals of 0.1. I kinda found how to do this for a single year but only in a way in which the values need to be adjusted whenever you use data from different years

Comment: There are folks on this forum who know exactly how to make common color schemes across different plots.  I suggest opening up a new question about that after doing a search on this site as I'm sure that someone has probably asked a similar question.

Comment: Perfect I'll delve a little deeper into my search, figured it was worth checking if there was a simple thing I was missing. Thanks for the help with this up to this point, it's something I've been dwelling on for a while now!

Comment: I used this methed on all of the data for a particular section of the river (both the data above and below a specific dam, so the data was in sightly different geographic spaces) but when I use the method on a section only about half a mile or less upstream of this section, I get the errors again. the data was gathered and imported using the same methods. I tried playing around with the data and looking for solutions online but nothing has been of particular help and the errors are persisting. I even tried it on a section further upstream and the same errors occurred.